# anchor tag not showing pointer cursor on hover?

Tags: html, css, tags, cursor, anchor

Okay, this is killing me. I've  normal anchor tags which don't change cursor to pointer on hover. I've tried defining cursor:pointer but no use. The anchor links are on this page

http://h-tech.pt/media.html

Comment: Which anchors are you referring to? The ones in the menu or those in the content (like read more)? Also, SO doesnt encourage questions where the code isn't posted here.

Comment: @harry Sorry i'm very new to stackoverflow community. Will take of it from next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `position: relative;` from classes `.landing-desc-box, .whoarewe-desc-box` (styles.css, line 145)